# ASP.NET 2.0: Skin files only work when placed at the root theme folder?

Tags: asp.net, themes

I have found that skin files only work if they are placed at the root theme folder in the App_Themes folder.

For example, if you have 2 themes in the App_Themes folder, you cannot add another sub folder to the theme folder and place a seperate skin file in that subfolder.

It's not much of a limitation, but it would give you more flexibility to further customize an app.

Can anyone shed light on why this behavior occurs as it does in 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

Has your skin file should have the extension .skin? I always call them theme.skin and give them the same name as the folder. Eg in Theme col2, the folder is

App_Themes\col2
and contains the css and col2.skin

[Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247256(VS.80).aspx) is your best reference:

Answer (score 1):

Themes in ASP.Net don't provide the ability to choose from "sub-themes".

However, you can set SkinIDs in your skin files. For example, in your .skin :

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" SkinID="DataListColor" Width="100%">
  <ItemStyle BackColor="Blue" ForeColor="Red" />
</asp:DataList>

<asp:DataList runat="server" SkinID="DataListSmall" Width="50%">
</asp:DataList>
```

Then, when you want to call one of them, you just specify which SkinID you want for your datalist.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to change this behavior is via a **VirtualPathProvider** - something along the lines of: 
http://www.neovolve.com/page/ASPNet-Virtual-Theme-Provider-10.aspx